# Firefox 19 on Mac and Arial Narrow

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts

I'm having trouble figuring out why Arial Narrow is displaying correctly for some Firefox users on mac and not others. Here is the link: http://teknikor.bethmotta.com/ (see navigation font)

My code is:

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial  sans-serif; font-weight:500; 
font-stretch:condensed;
```

I even tried adding a font reset:

```
font-family: inherit; font-stretch:inherit; font-style:inherit;
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial  sans-serif; font-weight:500; 
font-stretch:condensed;
```

And I tried to target Firefox specifically:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
ul.navcontainer li {
font-family: inherit; font-stretch:inherit; font-style:inherit; 
font-family:"Arial Narrow", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-stretch:condensed;}  
}
```

I'm not sure why it works for some Firefox mac users and not for others. All tested computers are operating Firefox 19. In the computers where Arial Narrow is not working the font is defaulting to Times not Arial.

I did notice that on the computers where it displaying correctly, Arial Narrow is installed in the user library as well as the system library. On computers where I am seeing Times, Arial Narrow is only in the system library, not the user library... however, Arial is installed in both, so why is the navigation defaulting to Times?

In general, does Firefox target fonts within the mac user library or system library?

Any other suggestions on how to fix this? Am I missing something simple?

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well I figured something out if anyone is interested. I added "arial" in lowercase to the stylesheet and Firefox defaulted to arial rather than Times.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following CSS3 rule:

```
@font-face { font-family: Arial Narrow;
src: url('ArialN.ttf'),
     url('ArialN.eot'); /* IE9+ */
```

To make it work, you need to **include the font file(!)** to the appropriate folder.

Example of use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@font-face { font-family: Arial Narrow;
    src: url('ArialN.ttf'),
         url('ArialN.eot'); /* IE9+ */
}
div{font-family:Arial Narrow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9+ only supports fonts of type .eot. Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the new @font-face rule.</p>

</body>
</html>
```